# Logit to calculate the likelihood of distress in a firm

Tags: logit, finance, valuation

Suppose I use a logit model to calculate the probability of financial distress for a firm.

I use some ratios that I believe are relevant in determining the success/failure of a Company and, using past data of firms (some of them failing other no), I can run my logit, right?

Now, how can I get the probability of distress from the logit output?
I am doing this using R, so if you can also make examples with this language, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some more information? Sample size? How many variables? What kind of variables?